# Form HTML Validation error in asp.net webform 4.0

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

I am getting following validation error 
`Bad value for attribute action on element form: Must be non-empty.`
`<form method="post" action="" id="form1">`

Below is my HTML Schema. I am using visual studio 2010, I previous i didnt has this kind of error as was using html 4 with strict html type....

This time i am using HTML5 type template but it keeps getting me this error even i tried adding `action=""` it still generates this error. I looked for solution but so far i am not able to find any fix am i doing anything wrong...

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SiteMasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en-US">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1"  runat="server">
....
....
....
</body>
</html>
```

Update: I am getting HTML validation error on http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real error.

Please understand that master page is not run by himself, but with a page that use it.
Until you set him a page did not know what to place on `action`. On action is set the filename of the page that will be the post back. Master page not run by himself anyway, so did not know what to place there. So when you attach him a page to the master page, the action will be set.

Also you run the validation on the non rendering code ! that have no sense. Run the validation on the final page creation. The code that is used on code behind is not pass any html validation, because is simple did not have been fixed yet as final html page.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. I am getting HTML validation error on http://validator.w3.org website while i try to validate my HTML

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker You get html validation error, on a page that is **NOT html**, but `.aspx` code, actually `.master` code. Simple the validation is not work for `.aspx` pages. After your run your final page, and the html is generated, there run the validation, on the final html rendered page.

Comment: You are right, When i test URL it give me same error but when us test code (http://validator.w3.org) only it passes with flying colors.. Thanks..